# Adding two columns from two different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables with same field types. Fields that are common in here are *BG_ID* and *Store Number*. Now I want to *SUM* two columns (*total_area* and *total_area_blk*) from two tables and group them by BG_ID .

The following is what I tried which doesnt work:

```
 select t.bg_id, t.store_number,sum(a.total_area),sum(b.total_area_blk)
 from (select bg_id,store_number,total_area
 from temp_Prop_area_block a
 where store_number='33665'
 union all
 select bg_id,store_number,total_area_blk 
 from temp_Prop_area_BG b
 where store_number='33665')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope, this helps you!

```
SELECT bg_id,  store_number,  SUM(total_area)
FROM
  (
    SELECT bg_id,  store_number,  total_area as total_area
    FROM temp_Prop_area_block a
    WHERE store_number='33665'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT bg_id,   store_number,  total_area_blk as total_area
    FROM temp_Prop_area_BG b
    WHERE store_number='33665'
  ) my_view
GROUP BY bg_id, store_number;
```

Comment: area fields are different in two tables . one is total_area and other is total_area_blk

Comment: When we do union, the resultset will be clubbed and the column alias will turn up as the first UNION part's column name.. So now, total_area itself will do, and it holds both values.. Added alias to my query for readability!

Comment: This one returns no output.

Comment: Just try to run the Inner Sub Query only and see the results.. Reason should be with your `WHERE` condition.

Comment: This also doesnt return any output.

Comment: So, you use bind variable? Does `SELECT *` returns any row? If `store_number` is of `CHAR` , you may need to do a `RPAD` to make up to the column size,(When bind variable is Used or in a `PL/SQL` as variable)